# java smartcardio request shared access

Tags: java, smartcard, smartcard-reader, pcsc

I am using javax.smartcardio. How can I check if a terminal / card are open in exclusive mode from other programs ?

I found the suggestion [use the Card method checkExclusive()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592634/exclusive-access-established-by-another-thread-java-smartcardio)
but with JDK 1.7 the compilation fails :

> error: cannot find symbol